# How can I combine multi regex together in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I combine multi regex together in javascript?

I have 3 regexes and want to combine them together.

```
const VALUE="qwer1234"

const pattern1 = /^.{5,20}/
const pattern2 = /[a-zA-Z]/
const pattern3 = /\d/

if(pattern1.test(VALUE) && pattern2.test(VALUE) && pattern3.test(VALUE)){
  // do something...
}
```

I tried and could not solve it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you plase clarify if you need a text that can have letters and numbers, or if it must have at least a letter and at least a number? Can you please tell us if there's a limit on the size of the text (currently texts with size 30 are valid)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write more complex patterns. Like:

```js
const pattern = /^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$/
```

`^` Start of the string

`?=.*?[a-zA-Z]` Atleast one letter

`?=.*?[0-9]` Atteast one digit

`[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}` Between 5 to 20 letters or digits. You can replace this part with `.{5,20}` if you want to allow any other characters too.

`$` End of the string

I think what you were trying to match was a string with 5 to 20 lowercase and uppercase characters and digits. If so instead of writing it in different patterns you need to find a way to describe every condition in one pattern. I recommend using a tool like: https://regex101.com/ to speed up testing different patterns.

Comment: thanks for replying, my VALUE must have at least one number and letter, based on your pattern does it not work?

Comment: Oh, shoot. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I'd also make an edit to the title of your question If you approve the pending edit.